# General statements for the second derivative of a function

Tags: calculus, functions

I am working on a task about second derivative. The task is:

$f(x)$ on $(-1,1)$ has the values $f(-1)=-10$, $f(0)=-10$ and $f(1)=-3$.

What can you say about the values for first and second derivative?

For the first derivative I use the mean value theorem and find $f'(c)$ for different intervals.

For the second derivative I have some statements:

1) $|f '' (c)|>\frac{7}{2}$

2) $|f '' (c)|>7$

Are there any theorems or rules I can use in order to check if these statements are true or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If we consider $x\in(-1,1)$ then

$$|f'(x)|\le k\implies |f(x)-f(0)|\le k\left|x\right|\le k\implies |f(1)-f(0)|\le k.$$

Since $f(1)-f(0)=7,$ what can we say about $k?$

Comment: We can say that k>= 7 , but I don't see how it can say anything about f ''(x). Sorry.

Comment: There exist $a,b\in (-1,1)$ such that $f'(a)=0$ and $f'(b)>7.$ Use that $7<f'(b)-f'(a)=f''(c)(b-a).$ What do you get?